# wp_query args with relation

Tags: posts, wp-query, query-posts

I'm trying to write a `wp_query` that will filter out posts with a certain tag only if they are also 1 month old. All posts older then a month without the tag are displayed and any post less then a month old is displayed.

After learning about date_query from a pervious post this was my attempt. However I found that `post__not_in` needs an `ID`, and OR relations are for `meta_queries` but I just want a regular query with 2 sets of possible solutions. Either A it doesn't have the tag and time doesn't matter, or b it has the tag and after a month it is no longer displayed. Alternatively is there a way I can just write SQL to do this?

```
$onemonth_before = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 month'));
$args = array(
  'post__not_in' => array(
    'tag' => 'x-post',
    'date_query' => array(
      'before' = $onemonth_before,
      'inclusive' = true,
    ),
  ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is wrong `post__not_in` only accepts array of post_id's only.

I think it should be like this.

```
$onemonth_before = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 month'));
$args = array(
  'tag__not_in' => array(<pass tag_id here>),
  'date_query' => array(
      'before' = $onemonth_before,
      'inclusive' = true,
   ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: How do I set the relation between when the tag is present and it requiring a time check though? in meta_query you can set an OR but for a regular $args it's not an option. I need something akin to doing a WHERE clause for SQL

Comment: You want set date option on `tag`?